# How to get the domain of the current request?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net, I want to get just the domain information?

i.e localhost or example.com

possible?

can this  value ever be null or its 100% gauranteed to return a value?

Answer (score 20):

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority`. Or replace `.Authority` with something more appropriate.